# How can I search through a nested list, looking for "a", but then assigning "b", which is next to "a", to a variable?

Tags: python, indexing, nested-lists

With user input I created a nested list

List example: `[[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3]]`

ex: My goal is to find "2" and assign it to a variable, but by only searching for it with a letter.

I was approaching the problem by having the user input the letter variable by indexing, and then adding one to the index. Below I have more examples of both ways I attempted to approach the problem:

`total_list`: `[['chloe', '2018'], ['camille', '2002'], ['hannah', '1979']]`
(individual lists are `peep_list`)

Let's say I want to know what year chloe was married, so I input "chloe". I am trying to search for the name in the list and then move one spot to the right and save that value.

```
person1 = str(input("Enter the name of the first person you would like to compare: "))

index = 0
age1 = 0
```

Example/ attempt 1:

```
for peep_list in total_list:
    for person in peep_list:
        index(person1)
        age1 = index + 1
```

Example/ attempt 2:

```
for peep_list in total_list: 
    for person in peep_list:
        if index == person1:
            age1 = index + 1
        else:
            index = index +1
```

Am I approaching this correctly?

Edit: My goal is to use "list logic"

Comment: Why don't you just cast it to `dict`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list` has the format `[[key, value],[key, value],...]`, `dict` can cast a `list` with this format. By casting to `dict` you can use the supplied name as the key.

```
data = [['chloe', '2018'], ['camille', '2002'], ['hannah', '1979']]

db   = dict(data)

person = input("Enter the name of the first person you would like to compare: ")

print(db[person])
```

---

If you are constrained to doing this with only "list logic", the below is one possibility.

```
data = [['chloe', '2018'], ['camille', '2002'], ['hannah', '1979']]

person = input("Enter the name of the first person you would like to compare: ")

for (name, year) in data:
    if name == person:
        print(f'{name} was married in {year}')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

`total_list` is composed of sub-lists.  In each sub-list, the first item is the name and the second item is the year.

So, as you iterate over `total_list`, check the first item in the current sub-list.  If it's equal to the target name, then print (or assign to another variable, or whatever you like) the second item in the sub-list.

```
name = 'chloe'

for sublist in total_list:
    if sublist[0] == name:
        print(name, 'was married in', sublist[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

So technically your approach is wrong but you were close. From what it seems you want to look for a name in your list and retrieve the year they were married back. This can be done much easier with a `Dictionary`

```
people_list = {} #here you are declaring an empty Dict
inputname = str(input("have the user input a name which will be used as the key in your dict"))
inputyear = str(input("have the user input a year which will be the value relating to the previous key "))
people_list[inputname] = inputyear
```

Now if you want to find any specific person's year you do this

```
name = str(input("now give the name of the person you want the year of marriage"))
print(f'{name}s year of marriage was {people_list[name]} ')
print(name,"s year of marriage was ",people_list[name])
```